# R calculating grouped frequency table with percentage

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2

Giving the following `data.frame`, I would like to calculate the occurance of each variable of `VAR` and the percentage of these occurence by the grouping variable `GROUP`:

```
GROUP<-c("G1","G2","G1","G2","G3","G3","G1")
VAR<-c("A","B","B","A","B","B","A")
d<-data.frame(GROUP,VAR)
```

With `table()`, I get a nice frequency table, counting the occurences of all combinations of the two variables:

```
d<-as.data.frame(table(d))
  GROUP VAR Freq
1    G1   A    2
2    G2   A    1
3    G3   A    0
4    G1   B    1
5    G2   B    1
6    G3   B    2
```

Now I would like to calculate the percentage of each variable for `VAR` by `GROUP`. So far I'm splitting the data.frame by `GROUP` and calculate the percentage seperately for `G1`, `G2` and `G3` and merging the afterwards.

```
d.G1<-d[d$GROUP=="G1",]
d.G1$per<-d.G1$Freq/sum(d.G1$Freq)
d.G1
  GROUP VAR Freq       per
1    G1   A    2 0.6666667
4    G1   B    1 0.3333333
```

...

```
d.merge<-rbind(d.G1,d.G2,d.G3)
d.merge 
GROUP VAR Freq       per
1    G1   A    2 0.6666667
4    G1   B    1 0.3333333
2    G2   A    1 0.5000000
5    G2   B    1 0.5000000
3    G3   A    0 0.0000000
6    G3   B    2 1.0000000
```

Is there a more elegant solution using for example the `reshape2` package?

Comment: Why not `as.data.frame(prop.table(table(d), 1))`?

Comment: I think this is a really elegant solution. I will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `dplyr`package you can do:

```
require(dplyr)

d <- d %>% group_by(GROUP) %>% mutate(per = Freq/sum(Freq))
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is coming from a comment by @lukeA and I think it's a really elegant solution if you only need the percentages:

```
d<-as.data.frame(prop.table(table(d),1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using data.table, you can do it as below:

```
library(data.table)
GROUP<-c("G1","G2","G1","G2","G3","G3","G1")
VAR<-c("A","B","B","A","B","B","A")
DT <-data.table(GROUP,VAR)

# Create count 
DT1 <- DT[, list(Count=.N), by=.(GROUP, VAR)]
# melt and dcast to get all combinations of GROUP and VAR
# as in your output. You can remove it if all combinations 
# not required
DT2 <- dcast(DT1, GROUP ~ VAR)
DT3 <- melt(DT2,  id.var="GROUP")
# Replace na values with zero
DT3[,lapply(.SD,function(x){ifelse(is.na(x),0,x)})]
# Create percentage
DT3[, percent:=value/sum(value, na.rm=TRUE), by=GROUP]
```

I tried to keep the output as your output. Hence had to do dcast and melt. These can be omitted if not required.