# frequency table for many variables, including percentages and separated by group

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

**Problem** I'm trying to create a frequency table for many variables, including percentages and separated by group.

I'm trying to use Rmarkdown to write a paper for the first time and such a table is quite common in papers, like in this link: [Frequency table from paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDyex.png)

The raw data comes in a tidy form:

```
# A tibble: 500 x 5
    age    age_group    cond_a    cond_b    cond_c
    <int>  <chr>        <lgl>     <lgl>     <lgl>   
 1     0   0-2          FALSE     TRUE      FALSE   
 2     7   3-60         FALSE     FALSE     FALSE   
 3    42   3-60         TRUE      FALSE     FALSE   
 4     0   0-2          FALSE     FALSE     TRUE   
 5     0   0-2          TRUE      FALSE     TRUE   
 6     3   3-60         FALSE     FALSE     FALSE   
 7    64   60+          FALSE     TRUE      FALSE   
 8    70   60+          FALSE     TRUE      FALSE   
 9     4   3-60         TRUE      FALSE     FALSE   
10    24   3-60         FALSE     FALSE     TRUE
```

**Desired output** The output should be something like this (the first line with n is optional):

```
         `0-2`       `3-60`      `60+`
n         20          330         150
cond_a    1 (5%)      33 (10%)    30 (20%)
cond_b    5 (25%)     66 (20%)    60 (40%)
```

**Attempted approach** So far I've tried using dplyr and tidyr, after all packages I could find (e.g., summarytools, questionr) would not work with the groups or were limited to single variables.

I was only able to divide by the whole dataset (per = count/nrow(df)), but the denominator needs to be the number of samples by group.

count/sum(count) wouldn't work either (as described in [a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35651058/r-calculating-grouped-frequency-table-with-percentage)), because multiple conditions can occur at the same time.

```
df %>%  
  group_by(age_group) %>%
  summarise(
    cond_a = sum(cond_a, na.rm = TRUE),
    cond_b = sum(cond_b, na.rm = TRUE),
    cond_c = sum(cond_a, na.rm = TRUE)
    ) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-age_group, names_to = "variable", values_to="count") %>% 
  group_by(age_group) %>%
  mutate(per = count/nrow(df),
         output = paste0(count," (",sprintf("%.2f", per*100),"%)")) %>%
  select(-count,-per) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = age_group_extended, values_from = output)
```

**Additional information** Ideally I would like to add some variables that do not need to be counted, e.g. median age, median of scores, etc. If there is a way apart from concatenating tables to add these, it would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Ahag, welcome to Stack Overflow. I think it will be easier for people to help if you provide more of `df`, probably something like `dput(df[1:20,])`. I would recommend providing the output by [editing your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62047573/edit) and pasting the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach with `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

The trick is that calling `df$cond_a` allows us to `sum` from the original `df` without the groups.

Additionally, changing numeric columns to `character` allows them to exist in the same column with the other results.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  group_by(age_group) %>%
  summarize(n = as.character(n()),
            median_age = as.character(median(age)),
            cond_a = paste0(sum(cond_a, na.rm = TRUE)," (",
                            round(sum(cond_a, na.rm = TRUE)/sum(df$cond_a) * 100,0),
                            "%)"),
            cond_b = paste0(sum(cond_b, na.rm = TRUE)," (",
                            round(sum(cond_b, na.rm = TRUE)/sum(df$cond_b) * 100,0),
                            "%)"),
            cond_c = paste0(sum(cond_c, na.rm = TRUE)," (",
                            round(sum(cond_c, na.rm = TRUE)/sum(df$cond_c) * 100,0),
                            "%)")) %>%
  pivot_longer(-age_group) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "age_group", values_from = "value")
## A tibble: 5 x 4
#  name       `0-2`   `3-60`  `60+`  
#  <chr>      <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
#1 n          3       5       2      
#2 median_age 0       7       67     
#3 cond_a     1 (33%) 2 (67%) 0 (0%) 
#4 cond_b     1 (33%) 0 (0%)  2 (67%)
#5 cond_c     2 (67%) 1 (33%) 0 (0%)
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps! I'll try to package it as a function and add that here, because I need to run this frequently and across many variables, I can imagine that others have the same problem.

Comment: I've added a function for the paste0 part that makes it easier to work with. I opted for not making a full function of this because I can now add mixed variable types. Many thanks for your solution.
```
format_freq_per <- function(df,variable)
{
  paste0(sum(variable, na.rm = TRUE),
         " (",
         sprintf("%.2f", 
                 sum(variable, na.rm = TRUE) / n() * 100),
         "%)")
}
```
note that I changed the sum(df$cond) to n() because on the real data set I ended up getting wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

You're basically tabulating and calculating calculating proportions based on the tabulations, so it's probably best to stick to `table` and `prop.table`. Here's an example of a function to get you started:

```
  myFun <- function(input, id, measure, display = FALSE) {
    x <- melt(as.data.table(input), id.vars = id, measure.vars = measure)
    x <- x[(value), table(variable, get(id))]
    y <- prop.table(x, 1) * 100
    if (display) {
      x[] <- sprintf("%s (%02.f%%)", x, y)
      as.data.frame.matrix(x)
    } else {
      list(x, y)
    }
  }
```

The function can be used as follows:

```
myFun(mydf, "age_group", c("cond_a", "cond_b", "cond_c"))
## [[1]]
##         
## variable 0-2 3-60 60+
##   cond_a   1    2   0
##   cond_b   1    0   2
##   cond_c   2    1   0
## 
## [[2]]
##         
## variable      0-2     3-60      60+
##   cond_a 33.33333 66.66667  0.00000
##   cond_b 33.33333  0.00000 66.66667
##   cond_c 66.66667 33.33333  0.00000
##
```

Or, you can set `display = TRUE` and get the following:

```
myFun(mydf, "age_group", c("cond_a", "cond_b", "cond_c"), display = TRUE)
##            0-2    3-60     60+
## cond_a 1 (33%) 2 (67%) 0 (00%)
## cond_b 1 (33%) 0 (00%) 2 (67%)
## cond_c 2 (67%) 1 (33%) 0 (00%)
```

---

Here's the sample data I used:

```
mydf <- structure(list(age = c(0L, 7L, 42L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 64L, 70L, 4L, 
    24L), age_group = c("0-2", "3-60", "3-60", "0-2", "0-2", "3-60", 
    "60+", "60+", "3-60", "3-60"), cond_a = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
    FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), cond_b = c(TRUE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), 
        cond_c = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
        FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
    "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "data.frame")
```

---

Ideally, "`display`" would not be an argument to the function, but rather, you'd create a different `print` method. That way, the values are still accessible in the `list`, though what is printed to the screen might be formatted differently.

---

If you're doing this for print purposes, you may want to look into the `tables` package. Here's the approach I would take in that case:

```
library(data.table)
library(tables)
DT <- melt(as.data.table(mydf), measure.vars = patterns("cond"))[(value)]

tabular((variable) ~ (Group = factor(age_group)) * ((n = 1) + 
    Percent("row")) * Format(digits = 1), data = DT)
##                                                 
##           Group                                 
##           0-2           3-60         60+        
##  variable n     Percent n    Percent n   Percent
##  cond_a    1    33       2   67       0   0     
##  cond_b    1    33       0    0       2  67     
##  cond_c    2    67       1   33       0   0
```

Comment: Thanks - this solution is more universal, which is very useful with many variables and repeatedly working on this issue. I've opted for the solution by Ian though, because my primary goal is displaying a table - with the function I've added in the comments it's possible to accommodate that in the summary function in dplyr so I can mix different types of statistics (e.g. count in one row, range in the next).

Comment: @ahag, take some time and look at the `tables` package if you're looking for nicely displayed tables. It integrates nicely in a markdown document and produces publication-quality tables.

Comment: Yes, it looks quite powerful, I think I'll need some more time to understand the syntax, but it seems to be the right tool for making nice tables from complex usecases